# How can I create a service name and password in redis-sentinel

Tags: redis, celery, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I am getting this error when I run celery beat -S redbeat.RedBeatScheduler.

beat raised exception : ConnectionError('Error -2 connecting to redis-sentinel:26379. Name or service not known.',)

How can I create a service_name and password in redis-sentinel
I am not trying to use redis as a message broker. I am using celery-redbeat to store celerybeat data in redis-sentinel cluster from this page.https://pypi.org/project/celery-redbeat/

and

from this configuration

```
redbeat_redis_url = 'redis-sentinel://redis-sentinel:26379/0'
redbeat_redis_options = {
    'sentinels': [('192.168.1.1', 26379),
                  ('192.168.1.2', 26379),
                  ('192.168.1.3', 26379)],
    'socket_timeout': 0.1,
}
```

I add 192.168.1.1:26379 instead of redis-sentinel:/26379 but when master node down in redis-sentinel cluster beat is down too.

```
redbeat_redis_url = 'redis-sentinel://192.168.1.1:26379/0'
redbeat_redis_options = {
    'sentinels': [('192.168.1.2', 26379),
                  ('192.168.1.3', 26379)],
    'socket_timeout': 0.1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have `redis-sentinel` in your /etc/hosts file it will not be able to resolve it to a correct IP address. You may try to replace `redis-sentinel` with an IP address of your Redis server. Furthermore, it does not look like a proper Redis Sentinel configuration. [Redis Configuration](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#configuration) section explains how to connect to Redis Sentinel, please read it.

Comment: I am trying to use celery-redbeat from this page https://pypi.org/project/celery-redbeat/ and I am trying to use this configuration

Comment: ```redbeat_redis_url= 'redis-sentinel://redis-sentinel:26379/0'
redbeat_redis_options = {
    'sentinels': [('192.168.1.1', 26379),
                       ('192.168.1.2', 26379),
                       ('192.168.1.3', 26379)],
    'password': '123',
    'service_name': 'master',
    'socket_timeout': 0.1,
} ```

Comment: please read this I am not using redis as a message broker. I am trying to store beat file in redis-sentinel cluster.